# Write in existing .txt file

Tags: java, android, android-file

How can I write in existing .txt file? I've tried multiple approaches, I've stopped on this one:

```
 private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {

        File file = new File(infoDirectory, txtName);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(data);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("Debug", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

But instead of adding string to the file, it re-writes insides.

**[UPDATE]**

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        File file = new File(infoDirectory, txtName);
        FileWriter append = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(append);

        output.write(data);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("Debug", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

**[WORKING CODE]**

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
        try {

            File file = new File(infoDirectory, txtName);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(data);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Debug", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: in your code, try this constructor for FileOutputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29, with an additional parameter to append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the file in append mode, which can be achieved by using the

`FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)` constructor.

Replace this line

`FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);`

To

`FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("yourfile.txt", MODE_APPEND);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't write anything. Check my Update section.

Comment: you are still not using append mode...

Comment: try this it seems to work with java 7
`try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("myfile.txt"), "the text".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}`

Comment: this piece of code won't work in android if I copy paste it. `Files` require `MediaStore` import, but `MediaStore.Files` does not have `write` method.

Comment: Checkout my edited answer and let me know if anything changed.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);`

Comment: Yes, it did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome mate :)